# How do I change the virtual environment from python 2 to python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, linux, virtualenv

I have a project made in `Django` in a `python` 2.7.16 in virtual environment.

How do I change the `virtual environment` from python 2.7.16 to python 3?

I’m using **ubuntu** `Linux` `virtual` `machine`

Comment: Are You Using Mac or Window?

Comment: I’m using linux

Comment: are you using apt or other?

Comment: Its ubuntu/Debian. And i believe you’ve already given an answer. However, I need help to migrate my project’s python virtualenv to python3 versions

Comment: For migrate you need to type this command `python3 .\manage.py makemigrations` and hit enter then you need to write this command `python3 .\manage.py migrate`

Comment: You should create a new virtual environment and reinstall the dependencies.

Comment: @hamza-lachi you totally missed the topic of the question.

Comment: @KlausD Sorry! if he need to change virtualenv he should need to make new virtualenv

Comment: @KlausD. Really? Is there no other way to migrate the virtual environment? Or can I create a new virtual environment and use my existing project under it?

Comment: @SowingFiber yes you need to create new virtualenv

Comment: You can use your project with as many virtual environments as you like. But there is no path to migrate a virtual environment. If you have a proper `requirements.txt` that should be done in no time.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks! I created a new env and now it works without issues. Please post an answer and I’ll accept that :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+change+Python+version